# What are the security measures of Apache Hive

Tags: hive

i would like to know what are the security features of Hive. How secure they are. Like hadoop security, What is Hive security?

Answer (score 0):

You can make Hive work with Hadoop security. Have a look at this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1264). You might also find this [presentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12453831/HiveSecurityThoughts.pdf) useful.